# What are the taxes I need to pay for revenues from an online tutoring business based in Washington State?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, washington

I initially plan to conduct business without any incorporation. That is, I plan to report my business revenues as personal income on the 1040 and file a Schedule C-EZ (or Schedule C, depending on how much I make). I have done this before for in-person tutoring before, so I am familiar with the process.

I was wondering, if I choose to take on clients in other states or countries than my state of residence Washington State, do I have to pay income/revenue taxes to those other jurisdictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've worked through the section on Washington's [B&O tax](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=82.04) to determine whether you're subject to that tax, esp. the "service and other business activities" tax under [WAC 458-20-224](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=458-20-224). The issue could potentially come up for [Hawaii](http://files.hawaii.gov/tax/legal/hrs/hrs_237.pdf), [New Mexico](http://www.tax.newmexico.gov/uploads/files/gross%20receipts%20and%20compensating%20tax%20act.pdf), [South Dakota](http://sdlegislature.gov/Statutes/Codified_Laws/DisplayStatute.aspx?Type=Statute&Statute=10-45-5) and [Delaware](http://delcode.delaware.gov/title30/c023/index.shtml). In SD, there is a 4.5% tax on enumerated services most of which cannot be provided except in person, but it also includes

> membership or entrance fees for the use of a facility or for the right
>   to purchase tangible personal property, any product transferred
>   electronically, or services

[Sec. 10-45-4](http://sdlegislature.gov/statutes/Codified_laws/DisplayStatute.aspx?Statute=10-45-4&Type=Statute) imposes

> a tax at the same rate as that imposed upon sales of tangible personal
>   property in this state upon the gross receipts of any person from the
>   engaging or continuing in the practice of any business in which a
>   service is rendered

and that state rate is currently 4.5% (there are also municipal taxes). Because of [South Dakota v. Wayfair](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/17pdf/17-494_j4el.pdf), your sales to SD customers could be taxed. The relevant issue is whether there is a "substantial nexus" with that state, as required by [Complete Auto v. Brady](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/430/274/case.html). The SD law defines the threshold for that level of business as $100,000 of 200 transactions, annually. It is likely that your business will remain "under the radar", but the court was not explicit about how low the radar can go.